# Issues with mean and groupby using pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have an issue using mean together with groupBy (or window) on a pyspark dataframe. The code below returns a dataframe called mean_df, for the columns mean_change1, the values is NaN, NaN, NaN.

I don't understand why this is the case. Is it due to the presence of NaN in df?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

np.random.seed(10)

data = pd.DataFrame({'ID':list(range(1,101)) + list(range(1,101)) + list(range(1,101)),
                     'date':[pd.to_datetime('2021-07-30')]*100 + [pd.to_datetime('2022-12-31')] * 100 + [pd.to_datetime('2023-04-30')]*100,
                     'value1': [i for i in np.random.normal(98, 4.5, 100)] + [np.nan] *3 + [i for i in np.random.normal(100, 5, 97)] + [i for i in np.random.normal(120, 8, 95)] +[5.3, 9000, 160, -5222, 158],
                     'value2':[i for i in np.random.normal(52, 11, 100)] + [i for i in np.random.normal(50, 10, 100)] + [i for i in np.random.normal(49, 10, 100)]
             })

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame(data)

# Calculate change

window = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("date")
df = df.withColumn("previous_value1", F.lag("value1", 1).over(window))
df = df.withColumn("change1", df["value1"] - df["previous_value1"])

mean_df = df.groupBy("date").agg(F.mean("change1").alias("mean_change1"))

mean_df.toPandas()
```

Comment: yes, it is due to the nulls in the groups. you could replace nulls with 0 in `previous_value1`

Comment: @samkart I see, thanks. However, that could be an issue because I will calculate the mean using a lot of zeros then. It would be better if there were a way to keep them NaN?

Comment: so, you want to exclude the nulls from the mean calculations? in that case, you could pass a condition statement to the `mean` function.

Comment: Using when( if null ).otherwise() ?

Comment: i might be wrong in this case. you have `NaN`s that creates the issue, as nulls are not considered in mean calculation by default. i think all you need is `df = df.replace(np.nan, None)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could replace the `NaN` with nulls, and then calculate mean.

```py
window = wd.partitionBy("id").orderBy("date")
data1_sdf = data_sdf. \
    replace(np.nan, None). \
    withColumn("previous_value1", func.lag("value1", 1).over(window)). \
    withColumn("change1", func.col("value1") - func.col("previous_value1"))

data1_sdf. \
    groupBy("date"). \
    agg(func.sum('change1').alias("sum_change1"), 
        func.count('change1').alias("cnt_change1"), 
        func.mean('change1').alias("mean_change1")
        ). \
    show()

# +-------------------+------------------+-----------+------------------+
# |               date|       sum_change1|cnt_change1|      mean_change1|
# +-------------------+------------------+-----------+------------------+
# |2023-04-30 00:00:00| 5355.116077984317|         97|55.207382247260995|
# |2021-07-30 00:00:00|              null|          0|              null|
# |2022-12-31 00:00:00|164.43277052556064|         97|1.6951832012944397|
# +-------------------+------------------+-----------+------------------+
```

Comment: Okey, and then join back with the original dad on date I guess.